# Locust worker not connecting to master

Tags: locust

I have locust setup in docker.  I have a master and worker nodes setup.  I was using a pre-1.0 version and have now upgraded to 1.0.2 and now my workers can't connect to the master.  I read through the release notes and changed the environmental variables.  Here's what they look like on my workers.

LOCUST_MASTER_NODE_HOST 10.200.202.13
LOCUST_MODE worker

and on the master
LOCUST_MODE master

Edit: Something interesting.  When i change LOCUST_MODE:worker to LOCUST_MODE_WORKER=true.  In the logs it says "starting in standalone mode" but it still connects to the master.

How should I be setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

This guide demonstrates how to connect workers to master nodes: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html

> To start locust in master mode:
>
> ```
> locust -f my_locustfile.py --master
> ```
>
> And then on each worker
> (replace 192.168.0.14 with IP of the master machine, or leave out the
> parameter altogether if your workers are on the same machine as the
> master):
>
> ```
> locust -f my_locustfile.py --worker --master-host=192.168.0.14
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the port `5557` must be mapped on docker and open on server's firewall.

Here is my **master**/**worker** docker-compose configurations on `locust`.

**master node on server 1**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  master:
    image: locustio/locust
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
     - "5557:5557"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master --expect-workers 2 -H http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8089 -u 100 -r 200 -t 100s --headless --print-stats --host=https://my-server-2-load-test.com -L DEBUG --html /mnt/locust/app.html
```

**worker nodes on server 2 and 3**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  worker:
    image: locustio/locust
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --worker --master-host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

remember to save report you should `touch app.html` file and `chmod 666 app.html` along `docker-compose.yml`.